# Assessing the Viability of Nuclear Initiator Device for Energy

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

Disclaimer: This question is purely theoretical and is merely intended to serve as a means of creating a model for a nuclear detonator-based power source. No association to weapons is implied.

Background: A theoretical energy source utilizes the detonation of a fission-fusion hybrid device. Approximately 3.45*10^-5 grams of Be-9 are struck with 1.7 MeV gamma rays, thus, releasing neutrons that may then become thermalized by the Be-9 layer. These neutrons will then become thermalized by scattering and (n,2n) reactions with U-238 and Zn-64 (about 2*10^-4 grams of the two). The exterior layer of this device is 3.8*10^-5 grams of B-10. The thermal neutrons can then strike a sandwiched layer of 6LiD, which becomes deuterium and tritium. The mass of the initial 6LiD load is 3.3*10^-5 grams. Optimally, the deuterium and tritium should fuse due to the heat provided by U-238 and Li-6 fission a crushing of the fuel pellet down to 1/20th of the normal volume.

Question: Would the presented amounts of materials be sufficient to detonate and cause D-T fusion to proceed? Assume that Be-9 neutron reflectors are present and that the necessary 1.7 MeV gamma rays are constantly irradiating the device.

Comment: You have way too little total material- most of your neutrons fly away without seeing anything. There is a reason reactors are big- thermalizing is hard.

Comment: *This question is purely theoretical and is merely intended to serve as a means of creating a model for a nuclear detonator-based power source. No association to weapons is implied.* Your previous [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/502984) only six hours earlier was about the effects of a miniature nuclear weapon.

Comment: @G. Smith That was to see whether or not there would be a significant enough shockwave from one of such devices to damage the casing. If a mere 10 MWth being released in an explosive was enough to destroy its containment, there would be no purpose in pursuing the issue further.

Comment: I just want to make sure I am reading the question correctly.  You are describing a device with a total mass of a few hundred milligrams, and you are imagining that neutrons will thermalize within this device? This suggests a lack of familiarity with neutron-matter interactions.

Comment: @rob No, they will not noticeably thermalize in the device. Rather, the beryllium reflectors mentioned will have the purpose of doing that. The neutrons produced by the 1.7 MeV gamma and the beryllium should produce lower energy neutrons that may be more readily thermalized by a layer of reflectors surrounding the pellet.

Comment: @SuperNerdsTeam This is the beryllium reflector with mass 34.5 milligrams, or an additional piece not specified?

Comment: As a further aside, "10MWth" is an unusual unit to describe an explosion. Over 1 microsecond that amounts to 10J which frankly isn't very much at all. One pound of TNT is roughly 2.4MJ.

Comment: @JonCuster The purpose of such a little amount is merely to provide heat, not a force capable of any truly destructive power.

Comment: I find the description of your device somewhat confusing, a diagram would help. However, this question is likely to be closed as primarily about engineering, not physics.

Comment: @PM2Ring The question is closer to physics, as it asks to see if there is the required amount of nuclear material to initiate a reaction. Granted, there is some engineering used, as must be done for every applied matter; particularly any of such matters being critically discussed on a forum with people who would like to know how it works..

Answer (score 2):

Lets be blunt - your quantities of material are way to small to expect any interactions with neutrons to occur in the first place. Since you have asked in the past about the 64Zn(n,2n)63Zn reactions lets just go there. For a high energy (~1.7MeV above threshold for the (n,2n) reaction), the total neutron cross section is close to 3 barns. The cross section for the (n,2n) reaction is about 0.3 barns of that total.

The density of naturally occurring Zn is, from data on Wikipedia, about 0.109 mol/cc. Assuming the molar density remains constant for 64Zn, you get an atomic density of about 6.57E22 atoms/cc.

Combined with the 3 barn total cross section, this means that a neutron travels roughly 5 cm through 64Zn before one can be reasonable sure that some interaction has happened. And, 90% of the time that reaction is *not* the (n,2n) reaction you are counting on.

Neutrons don't interact well with matter. And, you can't force them to do only one kind of scattering.

But, perhaps a larger problem is using 1.7MeV gammas to get neutrons in the first place. Going to ENDF and pulling up cross sections for gamma reactions on 9Be that produce neutrons results in:

[image: cross sections]

Near your 1.7MeV gamma, the cross section for the 9Be(g,n+2$\alpha$) reaction is perhaps 1.5 millibarns. You are going to need a lot (I mean a lot!) of gammas to get any neutrons in the first place. Then, you are compounding cross section on cross section in your proposed reaction scheme. That is why you need so much material to make something like a reactor - you have to fight those cross sections.